# How to do this in Visual Studio 2010 RegEx?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm tasked with taking about 50 old VB6 functions and subroutines and translating them to C#.   They're all pretty straightforward and I find that the majority of the work is manual editing -  taking an expression like

```
Dim rtb As Integer
```

and typing

```
int rtb = 0;
```

It occurred to me that there might be some way to automate this using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio's Quick Replace dialog.   The idea would be to replace all instances of the first expression, where "rtb' would be some sort of wildcard, with the second expression inserting that wildcard value in indicated spot.  But I don't know regex very well so it wasn't obvious to me.

Could someone please tell me if this is do-able and indicate the correct syntax for Visual Studio's version of regex?

**Edit:**  I tried two online converters, [Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) and [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).   I pasted in

```
Dim FF As Integer
Dim rc As Variant
Dim rtb As Integer
```

and in both cases got the same error:  -- **line 1 col 1: EOF expected**
Interestingly, if I manually type the code in they seem to work fine.    I tried pasting from Visual Basic, Visual Studio and from Notepad.   I tried adding leading or trailing spaces and adding a leading crlf with no effect except that the indicated line and column were always the first non-blank line.

Comment: One thing you may want to consider is a .NET language converter, like [converter.telerik.com/](http://converter.telerik.com/). It will translate VB.NET to C# - it won't be perfect, since VB6 won't translate directly to VB.NET, but I would expect that a reasonable percentage of the code will be recognized and properly translated.

Comment: I tried that -  it works great if I manually type the VB in but if I paste it in, either from Visual Studio or Notepad it croaks with "line 1 col 1: EOF expected".   So I think it needs more debugging before it's usable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use regular expressions for which they are created, you may look at code converters.

Yoy can try one of these:

[developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

[Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

But they can not guarantee the complete accuracy of output code.

Comment: I tried those and added an Edit to my post to show my results.    In theory they look perfect for what I need but they seem to have some strange line termination requirements. I got exactly the same error on both so they must use the same engine.

Comment: But back to my original question -  is there a way to do this with Find/replace and regex?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have access to Visual Studio 2008 or earlier, you could use the built-in VB upgrade wizard to convert VB6 to VB.Net.
2. Then you could use one of the free online converters that can convert VB.Net to C# (although they have their limitations). E.g. [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)

There are commercial tools that translate VB6 to C# like [VB Migration Partner](http://www.vbmigration.com/) or [VB Upgrade Companion](http://www.artinsoft.com/vbc_csharpgen.aspx), although it sounds as if you have a small quantity of code to convert and it may not be worthwhile.

Comment: The online converters look great in theory but I couldn't get them to work.  See the Edit I added to my question)   So back to my original question -  is there a way to do this with Find/replace and regex?

Answer (score 0):

Find what:

Dim[\s\t\r\n]+([^\s\t\r\n]+)[\s\t\r\n]+As[\s\t\r\n]+Integer[\s\t\r\n]*;

Replace with:

int $1 = 0;

Comment: Got "The following specified text was not found:" followed by the search string you suggested.   I cut and pasted it into the Find what so I don't think I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the right expression is without ";". Try this:

Dim[\s\t\r\n]+([^\s\t\r\n]+)[\s\t\r\n]+As[\s\t\r\n]+Integer[\s\t]*

Comment: It still didn't like the find expression - same error message.  Keep in mind that VS uses a nonstandard regex.  But don't worry about it.   While waiting I wrote a little C# program with a friendly UI that does what I need so I'm all set and I I don't need an answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I'm providing the solution using VS 2012 regex. In VS 2010 there are some differences. For example, you can't use "\s" to match spaces, and result patterns are \1, \2, etc. instead of $1, $2, etc. This one should work perfectly:

Find what:

Dim[ \t\n]+([^ \t\n]+)[ \t\n]+As[ \t\n]+Integer[ \t\n]*

Replace with:

int \1 = 0;